# Unable to connect to websockets

Tags: spring, websocket, sockjs

I am using spring-boot-starter-websocket for WebSocket connection. Server side configuration
[image]

Client side code:

[image]

I am able to connect to websockets when using locally (ws) but when I deploy the app I am unable to connect to websocket(wss). Any clue what I am missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to enable CORS in the spring configuration.